# Loading Scripts For Specific Template

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags

I'm attempting to load a couple of scripts based on the template in use. However, the `is_page_template` is not activating.
From my functions.php in the child theme I have:

```
function sectionDescription (){
if (is_page_template('taxonomy-tableofcontents.php')){
            wp_enqueue_script('descriptionsectiontitle');
            wp_enqueue_script('descriptionsectionbody');
}
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sectionDescription');
```

I can't see a syntax problem.
I'm assuming that you can use this conditional in the functions file to control the enqueueing of scripts, I can't find anything to the contrary.
As I've looked around at other examples my formatting seems to be correct.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on a possible source of the problem.

Note: The scripts are registered in another section of the functions file. When I first loaded the scripts I had the registration and enqueue together and loading on every page. This worked as expected so I don't doubt the syntax of the registration and enqueueing.

I added some test php to the page to test the activation of the `is_page_template` and it indicates that the conditional statement is not working.

I'm thinking that I don't understand how to use this conditional but I can't see what's missing.

Comment: Sorry, but `taxonomy-tableofcontents.php` is for displaying the 'tableofcontents' taxonomy archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_page_template` only works for templates belonging to the `page` post type. It appears your template is for a custom taxonomy, so you want to instead check  if [`is_tax`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax).

```
if( is_tax( 'tableofcontents' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter **template_include**.

For example:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'theme_check_page', 1, 1);
function theme_check_page($template) 
{
    echo substr($template,strripos($template,'/')+1); // index.php, single.php and other
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: I don't see how to get to the conditional from this. I'm not familiar with this filter but my short research suggests its used to control the template in use. Wouldn't I still need to add a conditional statement for the taxonomy in use?

Comment: Using this filter you can get title of the file and add this value into $GLOBAL and use anywhere you want.